# Performance issues vueJS and multiple Canvases in Electron

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, vuejs2

I'm working on a piece of software that contains n canvases where n is an array of tiles (where each tile is composed of an 8*8 set of arrays of raw hex, I won't go into details on that front, but suffice to say, yes it is a hefty piece of code to render each tile).  For the sake of argument, assume that the page loads 800 tiles; rendering each tile by cross-referencing pixel data with a hex palette.  My algorithm works well and is performant; about a second for the whole lot. the component structure of the system looks a little like below:

```html
<t-table>
   <t-table-row v-for="(row) in rows">
      <t-table-cell v-for="(cell) in cells">
         <canvas />
```

above the `t-table` component is my index.vue in which I assign key commands

```
  mounted () {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.keyCommands)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.keyCommands)
  }
```

key commands include a delete command (which pushes the user's selected tile's state to an undo cache and then zeros said tile's data at a given offset) and an undo command (which pop's the undo cache and re-renders the canvas with the previous data)

because of the volume of listeners required to have each  watch a store state for changes (even with a getter that takes arguments, i couldn't get this to perform well) it is better to manually perform the render command using dom commands: `document.getElemebyId(offset).firstElementChild` (I tried using `document.querySelector(`#${offset} > canvas)` but it didn't always behave reliably)

I am encountering unreliable behaviour with the undo function; the issue almost certainly relates to the asynchronoucity of the virtual DOM.  I've tried numerous different approaches but the bug is always the same:

```
// the following is performed in a single lifecycle

story # |                                     | bugs?
1       | deletes x tiles and then undoes all | none
2       | spams undo with nothing to undo     | hard to test, indication is none
3       | deletes x tiles and then undoes all | see below...
```

at best, on story 3, the undo is performed but the cache contains the tiles in an incorrect order.  At worst, the cache misses some or all tiles from re-rendering.

I've tried encapsulating the render and push to undo cache methods in Promises and then `awaiting` them in my keyCommands method but this doesn't seem to do anything in Electron as nothing happens when I hit `delete`/`ctrl z`.

I've also tried using lodash's `debounce` to limit the user input, unfortunately, this doesn't seem to help (if anything, the results are less predictable when key commands are debounced)

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

here's the main render function, should it prove useful:

```
renderCell ({ data, offset }) {
      if (data) {
        const canvas = document.getElementById(offset).firstElementChild
        if (canvas) {
          let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
          data.forEach(function (line, y) {
            line.forEach(function (pixel, x) {
              let p = this.palette[0][parseInt(pixel, 2)]
              if (p && p.hasOwnProperty('color')) {
                ctx.fillStyle = p.color
                ctx.fillRect(x * 8, y * 8, (x * 8) + 32, (y * 8) + 32)
              }
            }.bind(this))
          }.bind(this))
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't put a listener on huge amounts of components, instead have one parent listener that listens to all child events. Also, a canvas is meant for high performance pixel manipulations, so it's not a good idea to have a huge amount of canvases. Just create one canvas, and create all your tiles inside that canvas. Your performance will be tons better.

Comment: there's only one listener for key commands, I don't think that the active field listeners are the problem, however, yes, I'm aware that I might have to re-write my rendering process to one canvas.  I'd like to explore other avenues before doing so however as that'd be a significant re-write at this juncture.